# Import server configuration from one WebSphere to another

Tags: server, websphere, application-server

> I want to simply import one server configuration from other and
>   name and node can be different.

I have been reading about importing/exporting configuration for WebSphere server. And tried many ways to follow guide this official [guide](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/rxml_atconfigarchive.html) but so far no luck.

So I have `.car` file from friends server.

And if you want to know how did i export the `.car` file then,

```
right click on server > server configuration > backup
```

When I run following command on the server (where server name is same for me and my friend),

```
AdminTask.importServer('[-archive c:/IBM/server.car]')
```

it fails during validation and throws following error,

```
CommandValidationException: ADMB0007E: Server server1 already exists on node <node name>
```

now i thought this is because server name is same, so when i try to import this into different server then throws server2 (new server name) template not found error ,

```
.CommandValidationException: ADMG0253E: Matching template server2 could not be found.
```

**Note:** I am using WebSphere 7.0.0. Please also let me know so far during execution of this commands server need not to be running.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "import this into different server"? What command are you running when you get that last error about "Matching template could not be found."?

Comment: @lwestby import serverA config to serverB. And same import command.